# How to change ImageView arranged uneven to even in nested ViewGroup?

Tags: android, user-interface, viewgroup

I am working on nested ViewGroup in Android and I have used only LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, And I need to design an Activity like this shown in image below

[image]

And so I created this xml code shown below with nested ViewGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.akashpreet.cards.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/one1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/one3"
            android:text="OneName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="OneNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/two1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/b" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/two3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TwoName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TwoNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/three1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/c" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/three3"
            android:text="ThreeName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="ThreeNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/four1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/four2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/four3"
            android:text="FourName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/four3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="FourNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/five1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/e" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/five2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/five3"
            android:text="FiveName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/five3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="FiveeNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/six1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/f" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/six2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/six3"
            android:text="SixName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/six3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="SixNameDes" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But My output is not as expected, it is like the image shown below with uneven arrangement

[image]

Please someone help me to fix my code so that the ImageView is arranged evenly in my Activity, I have used a,b,c,d,e,f as the name for 6 image file that I have used in code and I have used some sample pictures not the exact one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem.

If I change this code in XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/one1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/one1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/a" />
```

In all my RelativeLayout If I add **android:layout_weight = "1"** and **android:layout_width = "0dp"**

I get output in Activity as expected.

Answer (score 0):

hi you are used view group but you have another option use gridview .
you are used linearlayout with weight=1 and orientation  horizontal now you add only weight = .5 to relative layout of image.

```
    <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/one3"
        android:text="OneName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="OneNameDes" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/two1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/two3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TwoName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TwoNameDes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the weight for you nested relative layouts.

This is happening because image height / width is not fixed.

change the parent relative layout of image as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/one1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />
```

Comment: I did the change what you said but still it din work.

Comment: @Aripit Ratan If i change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to  android:layout_width="0dp" the output is appearing correctly Thank you for your Help.

Comment: yes correct sorry missed that part. edit my answer :)